# Listing files in a HDFS directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Currently I am getting the list of files in a HDFS directory as below

```
FileSystem fs = DistributedFileSystem.get(
                    URI.create(projectDir), conf);
for (FileStatus status : fs.listStatus(inputDirPath)) {
     //Do something
}
```

The problem is this directory has a very large no of files. So this fills up memory. Is there a way that I can get a filtered file list like files which are created after a particular day.